# How can we authenticate a user via pin number without having username & password?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am developing a web application based on REST API and wanted to authenticate a user by his 4 digit pin number. User don't have any username and password, is it possible to authenticate a user by a pin number in spring security?

Comment: It is possible with a custom filter (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider).  However, does each user have a unique PIN, implying that you can have a maximum of 9999 users?

Comment: i didn't get what all inside this link. do you have anyother pin related authentication links?